# ALAssetsLibrary, NSMutable Array and UITableview lazy scrolling?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, nsmutablearray, alassetslibrary

I am trying to implement an application based on the ALAssetsLibrary fetching all image and video from photo library in ios4. I stored ALAsset into the NSMutableArray(assets),and then i display all video/photo thumnail in the tableview cell.
Now the problem is uitableview not scrolling smoothly,How can i over come this problem?

In the index of  NSMutable array(assets) having this type of values.

```
    "ALAsset - Type:Photo, URLs:{\n    \"public.png\" = \"assets-library://asset/asset.PNG?id=1000000402&ext=PNG\";\n}",

(or)

    "ALAsset - Type:Video, URLs:{\n    \"com.apple.quicktime-movie\" = \"assets-library://asset/asset.MOV?id=1000000505&ext=MOV\";\n}",
```

How can i separate only url part from this assets array . that is only this part

```
assets-library://asset/asset.MOV?id=1000000505&ext=MOV

assets-library://asset/asset.PNG?id=1000000402&ext=PNG
```

Is required  to implement HjCache in this application? 
Any other  way for over come this problems?

Comment: You have to use lazyloding concept here

Comment: yes, the problem is UITableview not scrolling smoothly.

Comment: NSURL* stUrl= (NSURL*) [[result defaultRepresentation]url]// result is ALAsset instance, the we got only url part of ALAsset

Comment: I over come my problem, if u want i will give details...

Answer (score 1):

f you consider the below 3 things,you will not have any delay while loading Photo-library images

**1. Store only the `ALAsset URL` into your `NSMutableArray` instead of `ALAsset`**

If you are using UIImagePicker, you can get it the URL through didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo delegate

`NSURL* mediaUrl = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]`;

**2.Use the ALAsset `aspectRatioThumbnail`  instead of `fullResolutionImage`**

```
 CGImageRef iref = [myasset aspectRatioThumbnail]; 
 UIImage *loadedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];
```

**3. Do the UI related stuffs in main thread.**

Because `ALAssetsLibrary` block will execute in separate thread. So the performance will improve when doing  UI related stuffs in main thread.

To do this either use

`dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue()` or `performSelectorOnMainThread`

**Example:**

```
 dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];    

 });//end block
```

**Final code should be look like as below**

```
ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset){

 dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    GImageRef iref = [myasset aspectRatioThumbnail]; 
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];   

 });//end block


};
ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock  = ^(NSError *myerror)
{
    NSLog(@"Cant get image - %@",[myerror localizedDescription]);
};


ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init]; // USE ALAssetsLibrary as single-tone or global while using ARC
[assetslibrary assetForURL:asseturlFromYourArray 
               resultBlock:resultblock
              failureBlock:failureblock];

}
```